# App crash due to class inflate error

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

i am working on an app which when i run is working perfectly on android 6.0.1 but when i run it on android 4.4.2 the app suddenly crashes saying class inflate error.
pleas help me. i searched and made many modifications to my code but nothing helped me. Some solutions include using multidex in dependencies and few other solutions through stackoverflow.

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}

**logcat**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: madevina.saveawatt, PID: 25177
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{madevina.saveawatt/madevina.saveawatt.ProductActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class EditText
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class EditText
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                        at madevina.saveawatt.ProductActivity.onCreate(ProductActivity.java:60)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/req_qty.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02009e
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2134)
                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:859)
                                                                        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:62)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:58)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1026)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1083)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                        at madevina.saveawatt.ProductActivity.onCreate(ProductActivity.java:60) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2130)
                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:859) 
                                                                        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:62) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:58) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1026) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1083) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                        at madevina.saveawatt.ProductActivity.onCreate(ProductActivity.java:60) 
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312) 
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**
**activity_product.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="madevina.saveawatt.ProductActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_product" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_product.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select product "
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_qty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/req_qty"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/req_qty"
                android:hint="Quantity"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_cap"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/req_cap"
                android:hint="Capacity"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_contactname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/req_personred"
                android:hint="Contact name "
                android:inputType="textCapWords" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/req_email"
                android:hint="E-Mail"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_cname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/req_company"
                android:hint="Company name "
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/req_mobile"
                android:hint="Mobile"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/p_addr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/req_home"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Select city "
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/pr_sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the app also crashed on LeEco mobile having android 6.0.1 where as it is running in emulators and few other devices running the same version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your xml  design.There is some error in XML file line #35..

Comment: posted both activity and content xml code...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its crashing because of the drawableLeft and drawableStart added to the EditText. Apparently android below 4.4 have an issue with that property. You can either use two xml files for the different version or use and ImageView next to the EditText to display your drawable. Note your code will work on any device greater than 4.4

Comment: Problem solved when i created layout for v19 and v21. Thank you